# NA button in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to default all buttons to NA?

or how can I create a button in Google forms where in by clicking on it all buttons will be defaulted to NA.

I am trying to create my Google form

Comment: Don't think that's possible

Comment: what do you mean by buttons defaulted to "NA"? which buttons are you talking about to start with? Please elaborate more, and edit your question with something more useful for others  to help you.